# Quadratic Forms

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms

When defining a quadratic form why is it that we place $\frac{1}{2}$ in front?  That is, why do we use $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}(x^T Qx) - b^T x$?  Is this simply a convention that comes from the one-dimensional case where we would have $f^\prime(x) = Qx - b$?

Comment: Can you explain your notation a little better?

Comment: I'm really not recognizing your definition of a quadratic form at all. It would help to include that. Definitely say what $Q$ and $b$ are (constants, apparently?)

Comment: Sorry, Q is a symmetric matrix and x and b are n-dimensional vectors.  It should be x^tQx, for example.  What I meant by the last statement was that it seems this 1/2 comes from the 1-D case.  Here Q is a scalar (from a matrix) and b a scalar (from a vector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This way $Q$ is the Hessian matrix of second partials. Also, it allows $Q$ to have all integer entries in some special cases of interest, such as
$$ f(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + y z + z x + x y.  $$

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!

Comment: Forgive me, I have the same question but I'm struggling to grasp your explanation. I still don't see why there needs to be a 1/2 in front of the first term. The quadratic form as defined in all the textbooks I've seen is simply x^t*Q*x. Is there a place where I can find this derived in detail? How am I to recognize that Q is a Hessian matrix of second partials?

Comment: @StephenBosch, just try a two dimensional example, $f(x,y)= x^2 + xy + y^2.$ There is no need for the 1/2, it is a choice.